# Using eles.restore(); to restore edges Not Working—what's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, restore, cytoscape.js

I have two disconnected components. One of them is a "control panel" and each node in it, when clicked, is to trigger an event that removes certain edges from the other, based on a weight the edges have.

```
cy.on('tap', 'node', function(evt){
  var node = evt.cyTarget;
  var clicked_val = node.data('value');
  // What is the value of the clicked node in the "control" graph?

  if (typeof(clicked_val) != "undefined"){
    // Only "control panel" graph nodes have 'value'

    var to_restore = cy.edges("[weight > 0]");
    to_restore.restore();
    // Restore everything, then...

    var to_remove = cy.edges("[weight < "+clicked_val+"]");
    cy.remove(to_remove);
    // Remove edges whose weight is less than those you want. 
  }
});
```

The line `cy.edges("[weight > 0]");` should grab every edge (in the non-control graph), and in some tests does seem to. However, `to_restore.restore();` doesn't bring them all back.

All edges have unique ids, that shouldn't be a problem.

Any thoughts appreciated. Am I not using restore(); correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You're querying the graph and then calling restore on the elements in the result of that query.  That means you're calling `restore()` on elements already in the graph -- having no effect.  Keep refs to removed elements to use `restore()` properly.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the trouble was if _any_ of the ids match things still in the graph, nothing is restored.